# Proof Of The Poincare Conjecture: An Unofficial Erratum

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, ricci-flow

We read and checked the detailed proof of the Poincare conjecture. One can find the article (Ricci Flow And The Poincare Conjecture by Morgan and Tian) on arXiv. Since the proof contains some gaps and errors/mistakes, it took us 6 months to get through the book. The detailed proof is over 500 pages long, so many things can go wrong in the process of writing. We filled all gaps and fixed all errors/mistakes that we found. That took us over hundred hours. At the end we were tired and checked only 99,99% of the book, but we are sure Perelman solved the problem. The Clay Institute, ArXiv and the authors gave us no response (maybe we are not famous enough), but an incorrect proof stays an incorrect proof, so we decided to publish our notes (109 comments) here. We did this for everybody who wants to understand the proof. This will save them time. Our notes can be found in our dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/73i5wz5390o1lx3/Final_Version_2.pdf?dl=0

If you think we understood something wrong, please inform us. Of course, some comments are only accessible to readers of the book/article, but we tried to make the errors/mistakes clear to any graduate student. The hardest error/mistake to fix was 97. You are welcome to check and comment our notes after reading them!!! Of course, some people will not take us for real. We only show that the article/book is not perfect. Note that the page numbers refer to the book, but our work can also be used for the arXiv version.

Wembley and friends

We are not interested in self-promotion. We just want to help the readers.
We all have a PhD.

Here is the question: Can you find more errors? Did we make some mistakes?

Comment: This isn't a site for advertising/announcing your work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for the reason given in the comment above

Comment: I'd suggest publishing your work on arxiv.org. This is a better way to share your findings than posting here.

Comment: I was also going to suggest publishing it on arXiv. Now I see that it is mentioned in the question, but I don’t understand what “gave us no response” means. Just submit it as a new preprint, you don’t need to contact the staff.

Comment: What do you think what happened when we went to arXiv and said: "Hi, we found over 50 errors in the proof and we want to publish the corrections"? They did not take us for real. You really do not know what you are doing if you vote for closing. Just read what we did and keep the knowledge accessible to others. Perelman solved the problem and we made it more accessible to you.

Comment: @Wembley That isn't how you submit papers to arxiv... Put it up on your own website and if people search for erratum maybe they will find it.

Comment: Well, if you like I can endorse your arxiv submission. My contact details are in my profile. (I didn't vote to close, by the way :-))

Comment: @jon - https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement

Comment: @ jon Yes, they just refused. A copy-paste-answer. We tried to be corporate.

Comment: The document in the Dropbox does not have the authors' full names. Presumably, arxiv wants that information, as well as verifiable email addresses. I also agree that, in addition to submitting the document to arxiv, it is worth posting it on your own web page. If your document really does help people reading Morgan-Tian, then it will become widely known and distributed.

Comment: @ Deane Yang: We submitted the work on arXiv with our real names, because we had to. It was on hold. We wrote them that we can make the article more appropriate for publication. They rejected. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @DeaneYang One can submit to arXiv under a pseudonym. All you need is to tell the secret to someone who can endorse and keep the secret. Verifiable e-mail is easy to make too: go to google or yahoo and set up one. Anyway, it is nice to know that somebody is still working on combing that monster (even though MO is not for such announcements).

Comment: @Wembley I took a quick look at the "Erratum". The issue with it, as I see it, is that it is written more like a set of notes for internal use than a coherent text. Part of it is due to its nature, but some remarks certainly would be nice to expand and make less cryptic. Also "We couldn't figure out what Cauchy-Schwarz has to do with it" is not exactly a mathematical statement :-) You know what? Try to send it to Bruce Kleiner and see what he has to say.

Comment: I do not understand how a post advertising an Erratum has no place here.  It is clear it's not self-promotion at all in this case.

Comment: @fedja: There is an inequality in our note. We wrote that one can derive it with another theorem. Quite elemantary. Please, write an answer how to conclude the inequalitiy with Cauchy-Schwarz. We do not know how. That's the discussion we wanted. We informed all the people, but they had to read the whole book to check what we wrote. Again, if you really start reading the book and come to this point, it will be big help. Moreover, what else should we write when x is actually z in the proof and when B is applied and not A. We were deep in.